# cin.get in a while loop

Tags: c++, loops, input

I'm trying to get input from user and give output until s/he presses 'n'. It doesn't seem to work. Is problem in scanf or cin.get? When I press y it just takes "tekrar" as an input, thus gives "y" as output and goes into a loop. Also, doesn't stop when i give n as tekrar input.

```
char cevap[300]="";
char tekrar='y';
while (tekrar!='n')
{
  cin.get(cevap,300);
  cout<<cevap<<endl;
  cout<<"Again? (y/n)";
  scanf("%c",&tekrar);
}
```

output:

```
Hello
Again? (y/n)
y 
Again? (y/n)
y 
Again? (y/n)
n
Again? (y/n)
n 
...
```

Comment: if you attach a debugger, you should be able to see the contents of `cevap` and `tekrar`.  Or you could just add a cout statement, so you can easily see the values while the program runs.  That will tell you if cevap or tekrar is not being updated properly.

Comment: mixing << and scanf can also cause issues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mixing the various input methods on `istream` (`get`, `getline`, `operator>>`) can be fraught with peril if you're not aware of which methods leave the delimiter character in the stream and which don't, and handle them accordingly.

In this case, `get` will read 300 characters of input or input up until the newline, whichever happens first. The newline will not be extracted, and so will remain in the stream. That means your call to `scanf()` will read the newline and stop, leaving the `y` or `n` you just typed in the stream.

There are several ways to reorganize this code to make it do what it seems like you want. This is one way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string cevap;
    char tekrar='y';
    while (tekrar!='n')
    {
      getline(cin,cevap);
      cout<<cevap<<endl;
      cout<<"Again? (y/n)";
      tekrar = cin.get();
      cin.ignore();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This uses `std::string` and the non-member `getline` to read input in such a way as to not require you to be limited to 300 characters (not strictly speaking related to the question, but good practice usually). `getline` consumes and discards the delimiter, but `get`, used to read the continuation input, doesn't, so we discard it manually via `ignore`.

Comment: I suspect you're using `cin.get()` for demonstration purposes, because it seems to me that using `std::getline(cin, tekrar)` would work just as well in that case (assuming `tekrar` were changed to a `std::string`).

Comment: Yup. I wanted to make as small a change to the original code as possible (I probably should have done it without getline, even, but I had to leave my desk)

Answer (score 3):

Use cin operator>> to read from stdin, instead of scanf:

```
string cevap;
char tekrar='y';
while (tekrar!='n')
{
  getline(cin, cevap);
  cout<<cevap<<endl;
  cout<<"Again? (y/n)";
  cin >> tekrar;
  cin.get();
}
```

Edit: fixed the infinite loop. You should use std::string instead of a simple char array.

Comment: This time, when i press 'y' it goes infinite loop. Doesn't wait for user to give the input (tekrar).